# Calc image height from width

Tags: css, image, height, calc

I have images of unknown width (100% of parent, parent size is unknown - responsive), images of different size and I need to set the same height for all of them.

I've prepared a small ode snippet to show you my current code.

```css
#blog {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#blog li {float: left; width: 48%; list-style: none;}
#blog li:nth-child(2n) {float: right;}
#blog li:nth-child(2n+1) {clear: both;}

#blog li img {display: block; width: 100%; height: calc(100% / 2.5);} /* 2.5 is width/height ratio */
```

```html
<ul id=blog>
<li><img src=https://picsum.photos/500/300>...</li>
<li><img src=https://picsum.photos/700/250>...</li>
<li><img src=https://picsum.photos/200/100>...</li>
<li><img src=https://picsum.photos/100/80>...</li>
<li><img src=https://picsum.photos/600/540>...</li>
<li><img src=https://picsum.photos/300/300>...</li>
<li><img src=https://picsum.photos/300/300>...</li>
</ul>
```

Is possible to set exact unknown height to all images in pure CSS, or I need to calculate that in JS?

*Note: I can't resize those images, a little deformation is acceptable for this case (incorrent width/height ratio).*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use flexbox where you will be able to use percentage value with height and the height will be the same in each row, not all of them:

```css
#blog {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

#blog li {
  width: 48%;
  margin:0 1%;
  list-style:none;
}
img {
 width:100%;
 height:80%;
 /* object-fit: cover; in case you want to keep the ratio and cut a part of the image*/
}
```

```html
<ul id=blog>
  <li><img src=https://picsum.photos/500/300>...</li>
  <li><img src=https://picsum.photos/700/250>...</li>
  <li><img src=https://picsum.photos/200/100>...</li>
  <li><img src=https://picsum.photos/100/80>...</li>
  <li><img src=https://picsum.photos/600/540>...</li>
  <li><img src=https://picsum.photos/300/300>...</li>
  <li><img src=https://picsum.photos/300/300>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know that question defines that little deformation is acceptable.
But I guess that object-cover and object-fit would be good option here

Comment: @HlibLiapota yes, if he's ok to cut a part of the image we can add `object-fit:cover` and we will keep the ratio

Comment: @TemaniAfif: looks good, but I prefer all images of the same height. Your solution has the same height in row, not for all images. Any idea?